# Is this a computed method name in a block declaration - or is it a typo?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am unable to understand this piece of JavaScript:

```
  Template.welcome.events({
    'submit form' (event, template) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
```

Is `submit form` the name of a method, with a space in it? If that's the case is the opening curly brace on line 1 denoting the start of a block scope?

Is this just a typo in the code and there's supposed to be a `:` after `'submit form'`?

I tried to put it through a linter and JSLint failed, but ESLint gave me unrelated errors about Template being undefined.

I found it on this example repository: https://github.com/themeteorchef/holiday-wish-list/blob/master/code/client/templates/public/welcome.js#L8..L12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample is using ES2015 syntax, and can be rewritten using the standard ES5 syntax as follow :

```
Template.welcome.events({
  'submit form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
});
```

In ES2015, you can declare object methods using a simpler syntax that avoids the more verbose syntax specifying them as properties being functions. (`property: function(){...}`).

```
const object = {
  method1() {
    //
  },
  method2() {
    //
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an ES6 shorthand for defining methods in object literals.

It is equivalent and compiles to:

```
Template.welcome.events({
  'submit form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah I searched after your answer and found this: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals